# How to prevent trigger from activating multiple times?

Tags: google-apps-script

'On Edit' triggering multiple email responses

I have a code that sends an email once column W is filled with an email address (which occurs when somebody edits column U in that same row). It is an 'On Edit' trigger. However, when I enter something in column Y it sends another identical email. I understand it is probably because the trigger is 'On Edit' and it is responding to an edit in that row, but how do I make it only send an email when column W is the one that changes?

```
  function confirmation() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var responses = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var range = responses.getActiveCell();
  var relevantRow = range.getRow()

  responses.getRange(relevantRow,22).setFormula('=if(U'+relevantRow+'="","","Changes Made")');
  responses.getRange(relevantRow,23).setFormula('=if(U'+relevantRow+'="","",C' + relevantRow + ')'); 

  var email = responses.getRange(relevantRow,23).getValue();
  var user = responses.getRange(relevantRow,2).getValue();

  var emailBody = 'Hi' + ' ' + user + '\n\nThe online banking request you have submitted has been approved, and all necessary changes have been made. Please check and make sure that you are having no issues. If you are still having issues, please reach out to the appropriate bank admin email box. \n\nAPAC: APAC.bankadmin@nielsen.com \nEMEA: EMEA.bankadmin@nielsen.com \nNAM/LATAM: NAM.bankadmin@nielsen.com. \n\nThank you, \nNielsen Corporate Treasury';

  var subject =  'Online Banking Request Completed'

  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, emailBody) ;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

function onEdit(e) {} has e (event) argument. You can consider e.range member to check where did the edit operation take place.

```
if (e.range.getColumn() == 23) {  // W column is 23-th
  // do something
}
```

Any code in place "do something" will be triggered only if a cell in column W was edited.

Comment: So are you saying I can change the script so that it will only trigger the 'on edit' when when a specific column is edited? And that is what the e (event) argument is? Thanks

Comment: Right. Read about [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). You can take not only "range" from the event object, but "range" is suitable for your question.

Comment: The onEdit event  will occur when a user edits any sheet but the script can limit which events it will respond to by restricting its response via conditional arguments using parameters in the event object.